# How can I prevent Hbase from overwriting existing values in cells?

Tags: hbase

Can anyone explain how to prevent hbase from updating the cell in the concrete column and key if the value already exists?
For example when the two processes in parallel will write to the same cell where `VERSIONS = 1`, only the last one will be present in the database, while I need only the first one, and the other should fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you force versions to be 1, HBase will only keep the last version stored. You could increase the allowed versions.

However, if you are having multiple hits to a row-key, this may be an indication of poor row-key design. Row-keys *should* to be cleverly created in order to allow for good partitioning and unique hits. This reduces hot-spots on Region Servers and improves performance overall.

For instances where you have a lot of redundant row hits, you should not be using a version limit of 1 unless you only care about the MOST RECENT hit.